# SQL / MySQL - how to get a unique week number (independent of the year)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to get the number of a week from a DATE starting with Monday as the first day of the week.  While WEEK() can partially accomplish this, I would like each week to be uniquely identified.  I.e., rather than rolling over at 52 or 53 to 0 or 1, to continue counting to week 54, 55, etc.

What is the best way to accomplish this in SQL?

Comment: whats your reference date? which week is 0th week?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the week numbers should be sequential (perhaps for calculating time spans), you can pick an arbitrary Sunday in the past that should be week 1, count how many days since that day, and divide by 7. (Choosing Sunday will make Monday the start of the week.)

```
SELECT CEIL( DATEDIFF( '2013-01-04', '1970-01-04' ) / 7 ) AS week;  # 2244
```

If all you need is unique identification, you could use `YEARWEEK()` to get `201253`, `201301` and so on.

```
SELECT YEARWEEK( '2013-01-04', 1 ) AS week;  # 201301
```

Comment: Could use [YEARWEEK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) instead of concatenating...

Comment: You could just use  TIMESTAMPDIFF  and pass in the interval week `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF (WEEK, '1970-01-04', '2013-01-04')`

Comment: Juhana's CEIL solution is the solution I was looking for, where each week has a unique identifier regardless of what year it is.  Using this to calculate overtime, so wanting to avoid using the year as it causes more harm than good.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use the following solution, to make a unique string from month and a week

```
id=str(time.month)+str(time.isocalendar()[1])
```